# concatinate two json objects

Tags: java, json

i want to concatinate the following two json objects.
how can i do that?
my json objects are as follows:

```
"Object1": {
    "Stringkey":"StringVal",
    "ArrayKey": [Data0, Data1]
}


"Object2": {
    "Stringkey":"StringVal",
    "Stringkey":"StringVal",
    "Stringkey":"StringVal",
}
```

Comment: What you have shown here is not valid JSON syntax. It is also unclear what you mean by concatenate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject) obj1.get("Object1");
JSONObject obj4 = (JSONObject) obj2.get("Object2");
JSONObject combined = new JSONObject();
combined.put("Object1", obj3);
combined.put("Object2", obj4);
```